# unreasonable system error of app while dealing with certificate ONLY when app opened from open command from cron

Tags: macos, cocoa, security, ssl, cron

I have application, which make dealing with keychain certificates. Everything working fine, if i'm running that app by hands, or by open command from terminal window.
But if i try to running app from cron or from ssh command remotely, i got error in that code:

```
SecExternalFormat inputFormat = kSecFormatPKCS12;
SecExternalItemType itemType = kSecItemTypeUnknown;

SecKeychainCopyDefault(&keychain);

//SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault(kSecPreferencesDomainSystem,&keychain);
OSStatus err = 0;
err = SecKeychainUnlock(keychain, 0, NULL, FALSE);
NSLog(@"Keychain unlocked: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL));

err = SecKeychainItemImport((__bridge CFDataRef)certData,  // CFDataRef importedData
                            NULL,                          // CFStringRef fileNameOrExtension
                            &inputFormat,                  // SecExternalFormat *inputFormat
                            &itemType,                     // SecExternalItemType *itemType
                            0,                             // SecItemImportExportFlags flags (Unused)
                            &importParameters,             // const SecKeyImportExportParameters *keyParams
                            keychain,                      // SecKeychainRef importKeychain
                            &outItems);                    // CFArrayRef *outItems

NSLog(@"OSStatus: %i %s", err,GetMacOSStatusErrorString(err));
```

Log of error:

```
Sep 20 10:57:00 iMac.local da[8805]: result.count->0
Sep 20 10:57:00 iMac.local da[8805]: Keychain unlocked: No error.
Sep 20 10:57:00 iMac.local da[8805]: OSStatus: -61 wrPermErr
Sep 20 10:57:00 iMac.local da[8805]: SecExternalFormat: kSecFormatPKCS12
Sep 20 10:57:00 iMac.local da[8805]: SecExternalItemType: kSecItemTypeUnknown
Sep 20 10:57:00 iMac.local da[8805]: outItems: (null)
```

As you see, in that two cases system doing wrong and don't allow me to import certificate to user keychain.
In my mind, i investigated two cases:
1. i got wrong user or group id while running from cron or from ssh. But i check id command inside cron script and see that id is a same.
2. currently i decide a same issue for push certificate by write them to the system keychain, and then my app from cron can read it from system keychain as well. But for that case i must write created blob to system keychain, which is gives me error (you see in code commented line)
3. i tried to moving to new API:

```
    SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault(kSecPreferencesDomainSystem,&keychain);
    OSStatus err = 0;
    err = SecKeychainUnlock(keychain, 0, NULL, FALSE);
    NSLog(@"Keychain unlocked: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(err, NULL));

    NSMutableDictionary * options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [options setObject:@"password" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];

    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

    err = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef) certData,
                                             (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options, &items);
//  err = SecKeychainItemImport((__bridge CFDataRef)certData,  // CFDataRef importedData
//                              NULL,                          // CFStringRef fileNameOrExtension
//                              &inputFormat,                  // SecExternalFormat *inputFormat
//                              &itemType,                     // SecExternalItemType *itemType
//                              0,                             // SecItemImportExportFlags flags (Unused)
//                              &importParameters,             // const SecKeyImportExportParameters *keyParams
//                              keychain,                      // SecKeychainRef importKeychain
//                              &outItems);                    // CFArrayRef *outItems

    NSLog(@"OSStatus: %i %s", err,GetMacOSStatusErrorString(err));
```

but same got wrError.

Any help appreciated in a all ways, i don't understand where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it's is a simple answer - app MUST running from launch daemon. Here is a good example:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3030/how-can-i-run-stop-relaunch-an-application-automatically-at-boot-login-some-oth